# Simplify y-axis values with seaborne ScatterPlot

Tags: seaborn, scatter-plot

I have the following pandas dataframe plotted as a seaborn scatterplot, however the default y-axis is very messy I have not found out how to format the y-axis.

```
x = sns.scatterplot(data=plot_df, x='enroll_cnt', y='grad_pct', hue='nrc_desc')
```

[image]

- Why is seaborn doing this by default, is it something wrong with my data? I tried different y-axis columns and had the same issue. I used `x.set_yscale("linear")` and was able to set the yscale, but now the percentages have been completely flipped.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries for your y-axis are strings now, as they contain the percentage sign. Matplotlib shows strings as a categorical type. This means the first string encountered is put at the position 0, the next at position 1, etc. Each time a string appears for a second time it gets assigned the position it already had. This means, your percentages get ordered quite randomly.

If you use `x.set_yscale("linear")`, you'll see these positions, but not the associated values.

The solution is to make your y-values numeric, and use the [`PercentFormatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter) to show the numeric ticks as percentages. Note that is has a parameter `xmax=` to indicate the value corresponding to '100 %', so it can work directly with the original values. Also note that the return value of `sns.scatterplot` is an `ax`, making it more readable to write `ax = sns.scatterplot(...)` and then `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(100))`.

If you don't have an easy way to directly create numeric values, you could change the strings to values:

```py
plot_df['grad_pct'] = [int(s[:-1]) for s in plot_df['grad_pct']]
```

Comment: I recommend overwrite columns values either with `[]` accessors or using the `.assign` method. You can really shoot yourself in the foot by assigning via dot-assessors

Comment: Thank you for the warning. Do you have a link or some more detail about how it might go wrong? I only encountered [this github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7175), which warns against creating a new column.

Comment: Well the main danger is that a user unfamiliar with the breadth of pandas overwrites a method like `max`, and then when they call e.g., `mydf.describe()`, very unexpected things happen. But if you said `mydf['max'] = values`, then `mydf.describe()` will work as expected